# Is it possible to provide different definitions for a virtual function of a replicated base?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, overriding, virtual-functions

I am aware of the statement, 
"A virtual function of a replicated base class can be overridden by a (single) function in a derived class."
I am curious to know if it is possible to provide more than one definition, in case it is possible—how to define and invoke properly?

Just to make it more clear, 
My classes and class hierarchy would be like

```
     A  A
     |  |
     B  C
     \ /
      D

//i.e., I am not deriving B and C from a virtual base A.

class A {
    virtual void f(){
         cout<<"belongs to A"<<endl;
    }
}
class B: public A {
    void f(){
         cout<<"belongs to B"<<endl;
    }
}
class C: public A {
    void f(){
         cout<<"belongs to C"<<endl;
    }
}
class D: public B, public C {
    void f(){  //This overrides definitions B::f() and C::f()
         cout<<"belongs to D"<<endl;
    }
}
B* b;
C* c;
D d;
b = &d;
c = &d;
b->f();//This would output "belongs to D"
c->f();//This also would output "belongs to D"

//Now I want to redefine f() in D like this
class D: public B, public C {
    void B::f() {
         cout<<"belongs to D::B::f()"<<endl;
    }
    void C::f() {
         cout<<"belongs to D::C::f()"<<endl;
    }
}
//So that 
B* b;
C* c;
D d;
b = &d;
c = &d;
b->f();//This would output "belongs to D::B::f()"
c->f();//This also would output "belongs to D::C::f()"
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Your clarification helps. Short answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is **NO**. – curiousguy

Answer provided by @curiousguy in comments.

Comment: You *can* self-answer, even by summarizing comments from others, but it should still be a proper answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator ...The question is "is it possible?" I thought it would be better to just answer as NO, as mentioned in comments. I couldn't find any references to other than that.

Comment: I completely agree with you. What I assumed from curiousguy's answer is that the standard doesn't say anything about this concept. So, the concept is not supported by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, you need to be able to tell the compiler which implementation you want to use.

One way to do so this way :

```
  A
 / \
B   C
 \ /
  D

struct A
{
  virtual void f();
};

struct B : public A
{
  void f() override;
};

struct C : public A
{
  void f() override;
};

struct D : public B,C
{
};

int test(int num) {

  D d;
  d.f();    // undefined
  d.A::f(); // Impossible because conversion from D to A is ambiguous
  d.B::f(); // calls B implementation
  d.C::f(); // calls C implementation
}
```

Comment: That's not a diamond, because you're not using virtual inheritance, so there's two A subobjects. The `d.A::f()` call should not compile, because it's ambiguous, not specifying on which subobject the call is done.

Comment: @GuillaumeGris Thanks, Can you also clarify the following.
In your code you said "d.f();" is undefined. I can't understand why it would be, because D inherits the function from both B and C. I expect it would be ambiguous. Your thoughts?

Comment: @GuillaumeGris Also d.B::f(); or d.C::f(); would invoke different functions that are defined in B and C, instead is it possible to redefine f() from B and C separately in D(so that there are two versions of f() in D) and when I call d.B::f(), it would invoke one version of f()(defined in D) and d.C::f() would invoke another function(defined in D)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a basic example of virtual functions

```
class Person
{
    int age;
    public:
        Person(int=0);
        virtual void describe() = 0;
        int getAge();
};

Person :: Person(int age)
{
    this->age = age;
}

int Person :: getAge()
{
    return this->age;
}

class Student : public Person
{
    public:
        Student(int=0);
        void describe();
};

Student :: Student(int age) : Person(age) {}
void Student :: describe() 
{
    std::cout << "Hi, I am a student, ";
    std::cout << this->getAge() << " years old!";
}

class Employee : public Student
{
    public:
        Employee(int=0);
        void describe();
};

Employee :: Employee(int age) : Person(age) {}
void Employee :: describe()
{
    std::cout << "Hi, I am an employee, ";
    std::cout << this->getAge() << " years old!";
}
```